# Persistent lump on dog's paw after jumping ant bite

Tags: dogs

A few weeks ago, my dog was bitten by a number of jumping ants. One bite was on a toe of her front paw. Since then she has been licking at it constantly. Comparing with the other paw, it is hard and lumpy.

Because of her licking, the side of this toe has lost its hair and the skin is pinkish. I am considering a e collar or some other treatment to stop her licking, but I wonder about the hardness & persistence of the bite reaction. There's doesn't seem to be any pus or infection.

Is this kind of reaction to an ant bite usual?

Comment: I suspect she is gong to lose a nail.  See a vet or just give it time.  If it gets bad (severely swollen or red)  see a vet.

Comment: I believe you are talking about the [jack jumper ant (Myrmecia pilosula)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_jumper_ant) is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Thanks for your advice.